# Can't get div to have an opacity of 1 when hovering over another div

Tags: css, hover

I've got a site I'm building using Oxygen Builder for WordPress to display a mega menu over the regular menu (https://www.extremeactionsports.org). It's positioned correctly. and when I use the following CSS, the opacity goes to zero, as it should.

```
#menu-sports {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: initial;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

All good there, but now I have another link that what should happen is when you hover over it, the mega menu appears. Code is as follows:

HTML

```
<a id="link-sports" class="ct-link-text atomic-header-4-link link-sports" href="#" target="_self"   link-sports="1">EXTRMSports</a>
```

CSS

```
a.link-sports:hover + #menu-sports {opacity: 1;}
```

Should be so simple but just not working for me. Any ideas why and what the fix is?

Should mention I did try the CSS without the + but nothing different.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you mixed up Classes and IDs:

Your link is labled with an `ID`:
`<a id="link-sports" ...`

But in your rule you to try to adress the link by an class rule:
`a.link-sports:hover ...`

You may try:

```
a#link-sports:hover + #menu-sports {opacity: 1;}
```

... if the rule really matches the HTML structure **(elements `#menu-sports` is direct following sibling after element `.link-sports`)** it should work.

Comment: But the anchor element has class links-sports as well.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the div has to be next to each other in the overall order. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

The + selector is very specific, selecting the adacent sibling. The space cominator will select descendants.

So, assuming that the #menu is placed somewhere below the a (anchor) element but is not a child of it you are probably looking for the general sibling selector ~.

```css
#menu-sports {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: initial;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

a.link-sports:hover ~ #menu-sports {opacity: 1;}
```

```html
<a id="link-sports" class="ct-link-text atomic-header-4-link link-sports" href="#" target="_self"   link-sports="1">EXTRMSports</a>
<div id="menu-sports">Here's a menu of sports</div>
```

Note: sibling means they must have the same parent.
If you alter the snippet to have a + combinator it will work in this instance because SO snippet system adds in the body element which becomes the common parent and there is no other element between the two.